# Slack Section Block: Markdown Preformatted Overflow Issue with long strings

Tags: slack-api

When using the Lego... I mean Block Kit builder, I need to send some pre-formatted data using markdown's "```" syntax, the problem is when it encounters a long un-spaced strings (such as a URL) the format breaks when displaying on slack. This is isolated to the block kit builder as sending the message through the app/web app shows up fine.

I tried using the `verbatim` property, however that did not work.

First block displays the error, second block displays correctly due to spaces being present and no long-words

````
[
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "```I_love_oat_cake_croissant_jujubes_tiramisu_pudding_pastry_sugar_plum_I_love._Apple_pie_powder_bear_claw_croissant_candy_muffin_gummi_bears.```"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "```I love oat cake croissant jujubes tiramisu pudding pastry sugar plum I love. Apple pie powder bear claw croissant candy muffin gummi bears.```"
        }
    }
]
````

I expected it to mimic what a user's input would display when entering data on the app, which is breaking on long words when necessary, but instead the block is getting shifted off to the left and cutting off some of the data.

[Here is an example in both the builder and the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zbcs.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Looks to me like you found a bug in the block builder that you may want to report to Slack directly. Might be just me, but I can't not see any specific question. Please clarify

Comment: @ErikKalkoken hmm, I think you are correct.. This may be a bug to speak with them about. Looking through ways to contact them they referenced posting on SO w/the slack-api tag so I tried here.

**Edit** I reached out to them and this is a known issue; So I can only wait for a fix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently as of 4/15: This is a known bug so all I can do is wait. They do not offer a public facing site that lists known issues like this, but I have emailed them to track the bug and hopefully if it gets fixed soon I will update this answer.

Comment: It was fixed a few days ago :-)